# Как использовать поисковый класс zend c сниппетом advsearch в modx revo?

Tags: modx

В  [документации advsearch](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/advsearch) написано, что можно использовать поисковый класс Zend. Я положил нужные файлы в папку assets/libraries, тем не менее при указании в вызове сниппета &engine=`zend` выдаётся 0 результатов независимо от запроса. В документации написано, что нужно каким то образом индексировать ресурсы. 
Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

`docindexPath` - the path under assets/files/ where are located Lucene document indexes (default - `docindex/`)

Т.е. ты сам должен настроить `Lucene` на своём серве и указать ему сгружать индекс в эту папку. Тут могу пожелать только удачи и гугл в помощь.